# Render text as HTML in email template Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-365

I need to send an email using a workflow, either using a template or using the workflow step>>Send Email: Create New Message. 
The email must include a data field (Multiple Lines of Text) {!customEntity:Question;} which contains HTML tags. For instance:

```
Registration number <b>XSA-192034</b><br>
College <b>Private</b><br>
Principal player? <b>No</b>
```

What can I do to render the HTML tags within the Email template?

Template body looks like:

Hi {!User : Full Name;},
We received the info below from {!Contact:Full Name;}
 
    {!customEntity:Question;}

At the moment is being shown as:

```
Hi John Clark,
We received the info below from Jason Smith  
  Registration number <b>XSA-192034</b><br>
  College <b>Private</b><br>
  Principal player? <b>No</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will not work out of the box. You will have to get rid of your html tags if you wish to use it in Email Template or Workflow (Email).

You will have to use C# or java-scripting for this.

Look at these articles which will guide you furthure.

https://nishantrana.me/2010/03/05/converting-html-to-text-for-email-in-crm/

https://www.crmanswers.net/2013/03/converting-html-e-mail-to-plain-text.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your point, but I don't want to remove the HTML tags. I want to encode them to HTML in the email body/template as I need to show some words in bold. If OOB is not possible, what approach can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Then go for plugin, wherein inside your code you can use those html tags to perform your desired results. I believe attached ref links does show how to proceed.

Comment: @GabyMarquez if this helps, Please mark it as solved. It will help others as well.